# Convergence of series $\sum 1/n$ such that this decimal expression doesn't contain 5.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Study the convergence of the series $\sum 1/n$ where $n$ is all naturals numbers, and the sum is taken for all 1/n that not contain que number 5 in this decimal expresion.

For example: 
1 + 1/3 + 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/9 + ...

I delete 1/2, 1/4, 1/7,... because this decimal expresion containing a 5.

Comment: I think in means delete $1/5, 1/15, 1/25,1/35,1/45,1/50,1/55,\cdots$

Comment: No, n can contain a 5, but 1/n no.

Comment: Wait a sec, I misread this question when I voted to close. The previous question asked for decimal expansions which DO contain 5, and this asks for those which DON'T. Sorry @shanon, we'll get this reopened.

Comment: Yes, is different. @AntonioVargas

Comment: The $1/5, 1/15, \cdots$ is a commonly asked problem.  But if yours is different, that's fine.  Because it is not the common problem, it may be more interesting.

Comment: I would imagine that a more or less typical argument applies. Excluding numbers of the form $2^a5^b$ we can say that when $n$ has $k$ digits, the repeating portion is at least $k$ digits long. If the digits were random, then less than $\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^k$ of such $n$ would be included in the sum.

Comment: This holds for any given digit in any base. I voted to close as a duplicate, a number of times.

Comment: @martycohen This question is different; there, it sums over the set of $n$ whose expansion does not contain a given digit. Here, it sums over the set of $n$ where the expansion of $\frac{1}n$ does not contain a given digit.

Comment: I was not aware that this question was asked, so I asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643376/variation-of-the-kempner-series-convergence-of-series-sum-frac1n-where).

Comment: I answered @Watson's question, so we can now rightfully close this one as a duplicate again.